# Using insertion sort to sort input data

Tags: python, python-2.7, insertion-sort

I am trying to use insertion sort to sort data in an input file but the code doesn't seem to work! Am I over complicating it? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
input_file = open('C:\\Users\\Desktop\\data.txt', 'r') 
for line in input_file:
    print line

def insertion_sort(items):
    for i in range (1, len(items)):
        j=i
        while j>0 and items[j]<items [j-1]:
            temp = items[j]
            items [j]=items[j-1]
            items [j-1]=temp
            j=j-1

insertion_sort(input_file)
print 'After sorting:', input_file

input_file.close()
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work"? What does it output on what example input?

Comment: can you replace the input file with a hard coded input so that we can test the behavior?

Comment: This is not an insertion sort. Seems more like some kind of bubble sort.

Comment: And it seems you are giving the File object as the input for that function, and latter trying to change it. I doubt this to be an accepted operation.

Comment: Maybe you need to write back to the file.

Comment: It *is* an insertion sort, although the implementation isn't the most efficient. (The difference between insertion sort and bubble sort is roughly as follows. A bubble sort goes 1 12 123 1234 12345 etc., always doing all comparisons in each group. An insertion sort goes 1 21 321 4321 54321 etc., stopping each group early once it's found the right place for the latest item. This code is doing the latter.)

Answer (score 3):

What you are passing to `insertion_sort` is a *file object*. It looks to me as if your `insertion_sort` function expects something more like a *list* whose contents it can mess with.

A file object is "iterable", which (among other things) means you can make a list out of its contents: `list(input_file)` will be a list, with one element per line in the file. But note that iterating over the lines -- as you do right at the start -- moves past them, and after printing out all the lines `list(input_file)` will be an empty list. So if you want to make a list out of the file, you should do it immediately after opening the file.

Changing the list will not change the contents of the file. If you want to do that, you will need to write it out again.

Answer (score 0):

By just looking at your code, I guess it outputs nothing in the sorted list for the simple reason that you're already exhausting the generator returning lines from the file to print it in unsorted order.

Store the lines in a list and iterate over that to print it, then you can still reuse the list later for processing.

```
input_file = open('C:\\Users\\Desktop\\data.txt', 'r') 
input_lines = input_file.readlines()

for line in input_lines:
    print line

insertion_sort(input_lines)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
#use 'with' statement so context manager will handle possible exceptions and close file
with open('C:\\Users\\Desktop\\data.txt', 'r'):
    def insertion_sort(sort_list):
        for i in range(0, len(sort_list)):
            j = i
            while j > 0 and sort_list[j - 1] < sort_list[j]:
                #some sugar to avoid temp variable
                sort_list[j - 1], sort_list[j] = sort_list[j], sort_list[j - 1]
                j = j - 1

    #make a list of file iterator
    list_to_sort = list(input_file)
    print 'Before:', list_to_sort
    insertion_sort(list_to_sort)
    print 'After:', list_to_sort
```

As was mentioned in the answer above when you open file you get an iterator. If you want an object you can play with (modify its contents) and this is certainly the case you can make a list of this iterator. And as you opened you file in a read-only mode you can not write results of our function there. And if you need to write results back to your file you should open it in 'r+' mode as 'r' is read-only.